# Does Marathon has a "exec" command?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, mesos, marathon

As you know, there is a "docker exec" command in Docker to execute a command in a container.
There is a "kubectl exec "command in K8S to execute a command in a K8S poc.
So, is there a "marathon exec " like command in Marathon to execute commands in Marathon App?

The detail scenario is: we use Marathon as our container orchestration tool. And we deploy Ceph RGW by Marathon. After deployment, we want create a S3 user by command `"radosgw-admin user create"`, which can only be executed in shell. 
As a result, how can I implement this situation.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't come across the exec command on Marathon. However, there is dcos task executor which is used to execute the commands inside the containers. pretty much similar to docker exec.
https://docs.mesosphere.com/1.9/monitoring/debugging/task-exec/

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I think it's exactly what I want, I will try it later. Any more, is there any Java library of `dcos task exec`?  Sorry I did do some search on this, but I didn't find any.

Comment: DC/OS is a data center distributed operating system based on Apache Mesos. Which is an interesting one and there is a lot to learn. Online tutorials are available. [link](https://dcos.io/)

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the only option is to SSH to the machine with the Docker task, then docker exec from there